# Call a function after the Recyclerview is created

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I would like to insert a tutorial on my list of Cardview using a library. For this library I need to give a view (element pointed) but my `mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForItemId(mAdapter.getItemId(1)).itemView` always returns null. Why does this return null? Because the recycle view is not yet created?

I also try to replace it with : `mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForItemId(mAdapter.getItemId(1)).itemView)`

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_players);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view_list_player);

        // use this setting to improve performance if you know that changes
        // in content do not change the layout size of the RecyclerView
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        // use a linear layout manager
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        // specify an adapter (see also next example)
        mDataset = Data.bdd.get_list_players();
        mAdapter = new CardsViewAdapter(mDataset);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Tutorial
        new MaterialIntroView.Builder(this)
                .enableDotAnimation(true)
                .enableIcon(true)
                .setFocusGravity(FocusGravity.CENTER)
                .setFocusType(Focus.MINIMUM)
                .setDelayMillis(500)
                .enableFadeAnimation(true)
                .setInfoText("Hi There! Click this card and see what happens.")
                .setShape(ShapeType.RECTANGLE)
                .setTarget(mRecyclerView.findViewHolderForItemId(mAdapter.getItemId(1)))
                .show();

}
```

Comment: Could you post your code which is returning null pointer

Comment: @Rasi Yes, sorry, I had omitted the last two lines. It is the last before that returns null: setTarget () takes as argument a view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way for me was to modify my builder like this and place my function directly in my adapter

```
CardsViewAdapter(List<Player> myDataset, Activity activity) {
        mDataset = myDataset;
        mActivity = activity;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your CardsViewAdapter library uses the default getItemId (which returns -1). You can use RecyclerView.getChild() instead.